# How to set paddings in ConTeXt

Tags: tables, context

I can't find a way to set left/right/top/bottom paddings in ConTeXt. I have a table. I expect there should be a way to set some space between the cell content and its borders. How do I set a space from content to the edge? I don't need to set indentation on a start of every paragraph. In fact I don't have any paragraphs. I just want to put Xpt here and there at random. How do I do that?

Here is an example:

```
\bTABLE[width=.25\textwidth]
    \bTR
        \bTD A \eTD \bTD B \eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR
        \bTD C \eTD \bTD D \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
```

Suppose I need all of them alighed to the left(align=right in ConTeXt) and I want each of the cells have a set distance from the border to text. 5pt for A, 10pt B, 15pt for C and 20pt for D.

Comment: If you work with natural tables, use the `offset=<dimen>` instance.

Comment: Also, please provide an example so we can help you

Comment: @JairoA.delRio I added example. offset is distance between cells. I need distance inside cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offsets also can be used for content inside cells. If you apply an `offset` it is applied for text wrt its borders. On the other hand, if you want specific offsets, add a prefix: `l`eft, `r`ight, `t`op and `b`ottom offsets.

```
\starttext
\bTABLE[width=.25\textwidth,align=flushright]
    \bTR
            \bTD[roffset=5pt] A \eTD
            \bTD[roffset=10pt] B \eTD
    \eTR
    \bTR
            \bTD[roffset=15pt] C \eTD
            \bTD[roffset=20pt] D \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Whoops I confused `offset` with `distance`